# how to scroll a horizontal panorama item correctly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a panorama app which one of its items is horizontal, but when I scroll left or right, half of an item either appears in the left or right and doesn't appear at the middle of the screen: like the third tile here

[image]

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="third item" Orientation="Horizontal">

</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

I want the item be viewed in three phases to let all of its content appear once in the middle.
How can I do that? thanks

Comment: Adjust the size of your content (rectangles)

Comment: Not sure where that comment came from. I gave the answer to your question, just in the form of a comment

Comment: @ShawnKendrot thanks for your answer. I don't mean you in my previous comment. I mean those guys who just downvote without explaining the reason. thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample Windows Phone Panorama App the size of the "tiles" are 173x173. If you adjust the size to be 140x140 you will be able to see the entire square

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="third item" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,4,16,0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,12,0,0">
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                <Border Background="#FFFFC700" Height="140" Width="140" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```